# Fetch DELETE method on Android (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I make several requests from a React Native app to an API. Every request works fine both on iOS and Android **except** the DELETE method that does not work on Android. The call is correctly made, it goes through the API and the objects are deleted. But instead of getting the response, the call falls under the catch statement with `[TypeError: Network request failed]`. This does not happen in iOS.

Some people with the same problem were missing `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` on the request headers which is not my case.

This is happening both locally, in testing and production stages (using an ip instead of localhost will do nothing).

The request is also successfully performed in Postman.

What can it be?

React Native 0.63.5

```js
export const deleteApi = async (api: string, body?: any) => {
  const userResponse = await getUserCredentials();
  const authState = await getAuthState();
  let response = await fetch(api, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: await getHeaders(userResponse, authState),
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  });
  if (response.status === UNAUTHENTICATED_CODE)
    response = await interceptor(response, userResponse, {
      api: api,
      method: 'DELETE',
      body: body
    });
  return response;
};
```

```js
leaveClass = async (
    uuid: string,
    onSuccess: () => void,
    onFailure: (error: string) => void,
  ) => {
    this.setLoading(true);
    try {
      const api = LEAVE_CLASS_API_PREFIX + uuid + LEAVE_CLASS_API_SUFFIX;
      const response = await deleteApi(api);
      if (response.status === SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE) {
        onSuccess();
      }
      else {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        if (jsonResponse.detail) onFailure(jsonResponse.detail);
        else onFailure(translations.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG);
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('leaveClass error: ', error);
    }
    this.setLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: did you try to install reactotron and inspect the headers sent  ?

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a network plugin for Flipper (https://fbflipper.com/docs/setup/plugins/network/), copy your request from it as a curl, and try to perform it from your terminal or postman. If it has the same error, the problem is not in React Native.

[image]

Comment: I've tried the request on Postman and it worked. I got a 204 with the correct body response. When the request is made from an Android device, I can confirm on the backend (Django) that the request also results in a 204 and that the object is deleted but for some that info does not reach the Android app.

Comment: my point is to compare what you have in postman and what you have in RN runtime, you can copy curl from flipper and from postman and compare it, do you see any differences?

Comment: In Flipper, I don't get the response (no status, request size, response size, time, no response headers...). I've copy the cURL command and execute it in Postman. Request headers are the same and I get the response with status 204 @Kirill Novikov